# Converter string para calendar

Tags: java, datetime

Bem preciso fazer uma conversão de String para calendar sendo que tenho que setar o valor em uma variável (que esta no tipo calendar) em uma classe e depois inserir os dados em um banco de dados!

```
System.out.println("Digite a Data de Aniversario do Funcionario");
 String data = scan1.nextLine();
 SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
 Date data1 =(Date)form.parse(data);
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime(data1);
 f.setDataAniver(cal.setTime(data1));
```

Comment: Qual a dúvida? O código que você apresentou já está convertendo para calendar. Clique em [edit]  e detalhe melhor qual a dúvida que tem.

Comment: o problema e que ao inserir no banco ele não faz a inserção corretamente! fica com os dados de forma incorreta

Comment: Então você quer converter Calendar de volta pra date?

Comment: Wander, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Como já foi dito, o código apresentado na pergunta já faz o que a pergunta pede.Imagino que você tenha criado esta pergunta supondo que o problema estava nesse trecho, mas essa suposição estava errada. Sugiro você criar outra pergunta e dessa vez coloque o problema que realmente está acontecendo e o trecho de código onde ele ocorre. Abraço.

Comment: O JDBC, API padrão de acesso à banco de dados com Java não aceita Calendar, apenas `java.sql.Date` ou `java.sql.Timestamp`. De qualquer forma, você precisa dizer qual tecnologia está usando e postar o trecho onde insere os dados no banco, pois como já disse, o problema não está na conversão de string para calendário.

Comment: @utluiz Obrigado pelas informações! estou usando hibernate! consegui resolver meu problema, foi uma falta de atenção minha com o código apresentado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supondo que a coluna onde você quer gravar esta informação seja do tipo `Date` e esteja usando JDBC, você pode converter o formato `Calendar` para `java.sql.Date` direto no `setDate()` do seu `PrepareStatement`, veja o exemplo:

```
    //...

    pstm.setDate(new java.sql.Date(f.getDataAniver().getTimeInMillis()));

    //...
```

Não há necessidade de formatar como `yyyy/MM/dd`, mesmo que o valor da data entre no formato brasileiro ou em outro formato personalizado no `Calendar`, ao converter usando `java.sql.Date`, a formatação padrão([ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html)) do tipo será aplicada, veja no exemplo abaixo:

```
    String strDate = "01/07/1990";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();     
    c.setTime(sdf.parse(strDate));
    //aqui está o "pulo do gato"
    System.out.println(new java.sql.Date(c.getTimeInMillis()));
```

Que exibe:

> 1990-07-01

Veja um exemplo acima funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/N5jssy)**.

Comment: Quase isso.... A minha coluna esta no tipo Date , só que primeiro eu adiciono a data em uma variável da classe Calendar e apos isso inserir no banco. estou usando Hibernate..

Comment: @WanderLopes a resposta atende perfeitamente a isso. Veja o exemplo da conversão do tipo calendar para o tipo date no final da pergunta. Se não for isso, então você está com dificuldades em expor sua dúvida.

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu completamente meu problema! Apenas uma falta de atenção no codigo, depois de analisar com mais calma encontrei meu erro. obrigado mesmo!